# Find is returning Enumerator, not object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, find, enumerator

I'm working on a Rails 3 app, and I've got a line in one of my controllers that looks as follows:

```
@features = Feature.find(:all, :conditions => ['featured_at < ?', Time.current], :order => 'featured_at ASC')
@feature = @features.find(params[:feature])
```

The idea is to grab a set of "features" from the DB, subject to some constraints, and then pick out one in particular from that set.  If the record in question exists in the DB but doesn't fit the constraints, I do NOT want to return it.  Thus I'm doing `@features.find` rather than `Feature.find`.

The problem I'm having is that the view needs `@feature.title`, which is generating an error:

```
undefined method 'title' for #<Enumerator:0x0000010216efd8>
```

Of course, I can sidestep the problem by replacing the above with this, where I simply define the constraints twice:

```
@features = Feature.find(:all, :conditions => ['featured_at < ?', Time.current], :order => 'featured_at ASC')
@feature = Feature.find(params[:feature], :conditions => ['featured_at < ?', Time.current], :order => 'featured_at ASC')
```

But this seems inelegant and a bit redundant.

What's the best solution?  How can I get my `@features.find` result treated as the `Feature` it is, rather than an `Enumerator` that lacks the variables/methods I need to access in the view?

Thanks for any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest this:

```
@features = Feature.where('featured_at < ?', Time.now).order('featured_at ASC')
@feature = @features.find(feature_id)
```

where `feature_id` is the id (or list of ids) that you want to pull out of the set. Only the second line will hit the database. The problem is that the `:all` option forces the method to send the query and return an array.

Comment: Being a Rails novice, I don't fully grok differences like why your code works and mine with `:all` doesn't (or why `find()` gives me application-halting exceptions if it misses, whereas `find_by_id()` gracefully takes `nil` in that case).  But understanding aside, it's a huge help.  I plugged in your `where` syntax and it works like a charm.  :)  Thanks!